# Append list element in pandas dataframe column depending on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, list

Whenever I try to append to a list given some condition, the value ends up being `None` instead of the list with the appended value. Example:

```
# sample data
data = {"bool_col": [True, False, True, True, False]}
my_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# instantiate column of empty lists
my_df["list_col"] = [[] for r in range(len(my_df))]

# append value to list_col when bool_col is True
my_df["list_col"] = my_df.apply(lambda x: x["list_col"].append("truth!") if x["bool_col"] else [], axis=1)

my_df
```

I've tried wrapping `x["list_col"]` in `list()` prior to calling `append()` to no avail. I'm not sure how to do this while retaining whatever list values may already be present and appending a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `apply` here. It's less efficient than a simple loop. You can mutate your lists directly:

```
for l in my_df.loc[my_df['bool_col'],'list_col']:
    l.append('truth!')
```

Output:

```
   bool_col  list_col
0      True  [truth!]
1     False        []
2      True  [truth!]
3      True  [truth!]
4     False        []
```

Your issue was due to the fact that `apply` assigns the output of the passed function and `append` doesn't have any. So you were mutating the lists and discarding them replacing by None.

Answer (score 2):

In your case: `append()` appends item to list in place and returns `None`, which is allocated to `my_df["list_col"]`. You want to return the list in your apply lambda.

Try this: `my_df["list_col"] = my_df.apply(lambda x: x["list_col"] + ["truth!"] if x["bool_col"] else [], axis=1)`

Output:

```
   bool_col  list_col
0      True  [truth!]
1     False        []
2      True  [truth!]
3      True  [truth!]
4     False        []
```

This should work for your usecase, since if I repeat the `apply` twice, I get

```
   bool_col          list_col
0      True  [truth!, truth!]
1     False                []
2      True  [truth!, truth!]
3      True  [truth!, truth!]
4     False                []
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I intend to `.apply(set)` to the column after I am done to remove duplicates. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To conditionally append values to `list_col` you can also use the apply method.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample data
data = {"bool_col": [True, False, True, True, False]}
my_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# define a function to append values to list_col
def append_to_list(row):
    if row["bool_col"]:
        row["list_col"].append("truth!")
    return row

# instantiate column of empty lists
my_df["list_col"] = [[] for _ in range(len(my_df))]

# apply the function to each row
my_df = my_df.apply(append_to_list, axis=1)

print(my_df)
```